# Having problems with setting up my Capistrano with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my Rails application using Capistrano.

My deploy.rb file looks like this :

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "xx.xx.xxx.xxx", :web, :db, :primary => true

set :application,       "myApp"
set :user,              "ubuntu"
set :deploy_to,         "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via,       :remote_cache
set :migrate_target,    :current
set :keep_releases,     3

set :scm,               "git"
set :repository,        "git@github.com:name/#{application}.git"
set :branch,            "master"
set :use_sudo,          false

default_run_options[:pty] = true

# default_run_options[:shell] = '/bin/bash'

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:keys] = ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ec2/keypair.pem"]
```

Now whenever I try to do

```
cap deploy:cold
```

I get an error just like the following :

https://gist.github.com/c54933142b900f9f93b9

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Did you do a `cap deploy:setup` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I am looking at that I don't recognize is the `set :migrate_target :current` -- this is probably the default or implied so maybe nothing to worry about, but the root error from your gist is

```
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xxx.xxx] rm:
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xxx.xxx] cannot remove `/home/ubuntu/apps/myApp/current'
 ** [out :: xx.xx.xxx.xxx] : Is a directory
```

`current` should be a symbolic link, not a directory, so it's hard to know how it got to be  directory.

I would log in to the server, change to `/home/ubuntu/apps/myApp/` then `rm -rf current`.  From there you could manually create the expected symlink (current will link to a directory whose name is a date/time), or alternatively back from your local machine run `cap deploy:create_symlink` then try a regular deploy.

I think it's fair to say that capistrano initialization is not it's strong suit -- once you get things going it tend to be ridiculously awesome, until then, more just infuriatingly obtuse.